# How can i call json parameter In PostgreSQL Procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Postgressql - 14 How can i call json parameter In PostgreSQL Stored Procedure when i do so i am getting thease error

-- Table

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_user (
        pk_user_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

        vhr_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        vhr_password VARCHAR(500) NULL,
    
        sin_record_status SMALLINT DEFAULT 1
);
```

-- PROCEDURE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_add_users(arrJsnUsers JSON[]) AS $$
DECLARE
    intSpStatus INT;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbl_user
            (vhr_name, vhr_password, sin_record_status)
        VALUES
            (arrJsnUsers.strName, arrJsnUsers.strPassword, arrJsnUsers.intRecordStatus);

        COMMIT;
        intSpStatus = 1;
        RAISE INFO '% User Created...', arrJsnUsers.strName;
        
    EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        intSpStatus = -1;
        RAISE EXCEPTION '% User Insertion Faild...', arrJsnUsers.strName;
    END;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

-- PROCEDURE Call

```
CALL sp_add_users('[{"strName":"ASD", "strPassword":"asd123", "intRecordStatus":1}, {"strName":"XYZ", "strPassword":"XYZ123", "intRecordStatus":1}]'::JSON[]);
```

--Error

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[{"strName":"ASD", "strPassword":"asd123", "intRecordStatus":1}, {"strName":"XYZ", "strPassword":"XYZ123", "intRecordStatus":1}]"
LINE 1: CALL sp_add_users('[{"strName":"ASD", "strPassword":"asd123"...
                      ^
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be confusing Postgres arrays with JSON arrays. If you want to use JSON arrays, the correct data type is `json`, not `json[]`.

```
select '[{"foo":"bar"}]'::json
```

If you really want a Postgres array of JSON objects, the correct way to initialize is:

```
select array['{"foo":"bar"}']::json[]
```